# I have a php error that is showing for no reason and want to find a way to fix the error or remove it

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in
>   /storage/ssd5/047/2981047/public_html/inc/sendEmail.php on line 47

OK
this error is being shown when I send an email from my own site...
I want to find a solution to this since the error is being shown on the site itself, not in the console, etc...

The message up is what is being shown on my site when the form is filled correctly...

Please, not I have no experience in PHP.

```
    <?php

    $siteOwnersEmail = '*********************';


    if($_POST) {

       $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
       $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
       $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
       $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

       // Check Name
            if (strlen($name) < 2) {
                $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
        }
        // Check Email
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
            $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
        }
        // Check Message
        if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
            $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
        }
       // Subject
        if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }

       // Set Message
       $message = "";
       $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
       $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
       $message .= "Message: <br />";
       $message .= $contact_message;
       $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's     contact form. <br />";

       // Set From: header
       $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

       // Email Headers
        $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


       //Error Starts is her if im not mistaken....


       if (!$error) {

          ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
          $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

            if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
          else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

        } # end if - no validation error

        else {

            $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
            $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
            $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

            echo $response;

        } # end if - there was a validation error

    }



    ?>
```

Comment: did you blurl $siteOwnersEmail variable which is at 3th line before send this message? if it wasnt you then you need to write there an sender email address maybe

Comment: On the top of your script declare an empty array ```$error = [];``` or instead of checking ```(!error)``` check for ```isset($error)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `if (!$error) {` the variable `$error` might not have been created - it only comes into existence when either the length test or regex test fail.
As the $error variable seems to be an array when it is created you ought to create a default empty variable. You ought to also check for the other POST variables being available before trying to use them or similar errors will occur potentially.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['contactName'],$_POST['contactEmail'],$_POST['contactSubject'],$_POST['contactMessage'] ) ){

    $error=[]; # default, empty error variable


    if (strlen($name) < 2) $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    /* etc */


    if ( empty( $error ) ) {
        /* try to send email */

    } else {
        /* errors happened - let user know or perform other tasks */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign default values to variable `$error`, for example

```
$error = '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, i appreciate it.